# Can we change the child owner in a master-detail relationship?

Tags: master-detail

Can we change the record owner name in a master-detail relationship when we create a new child record.

Comment: As sfdcfox says below, the detail object has no owner separate from the owner of the parent. Are you saying that you want to change the owner of the parent at the time of creating a new child record? These would be separate DML actions - inserting the child record, and changing the ownership of the parent.

Comment: Check my answer to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23834/apex-managed-sharing-for-detail-object for info how M-D impacts the Owner field.

Comment: @sfd - Are you asking if you can change the owner of the master when a detail is created or are you asking if the owner on a detail can be different than the master?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a custom master-detail relationship, you cannot specify an owner on the child record at all; the owner of the parent is automatically the owner of the children.

Answer (score 3):

The default behavior, as others have already observed, is not to allow child records to be re-parented.  There is an option to change this behavior.  It is called "Allow reparenting option" and is located in the master-detail field definition.

This became available in the Summer 12 release (though I only noticed it about a month ago).  I have not yet used it myself.  Here's a link to a release note:

http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Summer12/master+detail+relationship+expands

Added from comment:

Since first writing this answer, I have had the need to turn this option on for an object. Once on. you can re-parent a record when editing it. I didn't do any re-parenting via Apex, but I'd anticipate no problems with doing that. BTW, you can turn "Allow reparenting" off after you're doing updating if desired.

Comment: Since writing this answer, I have had the need to turn this option on for an object.  Once on. you can re-parent a record when editing it.  I didn't do any re-parenting via Apex, but I'd anticipate no problems with doing that.  BTW, you can turn "Allow reparenting" off after you're doing updating if desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can reassign records, if that's what you want. Depending on your requirements, you could probably accomplish this with workflow rules and definitely with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

We can't change the owner name via child object because child has no owner field in Master- Detail relation .
child record set owner automatically of its associated master record.

Check this -

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/relationships_among_objects.htm