# Master Detail Relationship

Tags: master-detail

I have master-detail relationship between A-B object. A is master and B is child .

Now the requirement is , that A must be public and B must be private. what's the best way to implement this.

Comment: Similar: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23834/apex-managed-sharing-for-detail-object

Answer (score 8):

Your only option is changing the Master-Detail relationship to a lookup. In a Master-Detail relationships, according to the documentation:

> The detail record inherits the sharing and security settings of its master record.

To retain the same features of a master detail you'll want to mark the lookup as required and and set it up to delete the child record when the parent is deleted.

Comment: Exactly. To add to this: You will notice that the child record in a master-detail relationship has no OwnerId field. Because visibility is controlled through the OwnerId field, it inherits the visibility of its parent record.
Alternate solution: Make the M-D into a Lookup AND make the Lookup relationship REQUIRED. You can do this when editing the relationship field.

Comment: Also, if you need a cascade delete, use a trigger.

Comment: Actually, cascade deletes are now an option on lookup fields.

Comment: Thanks Everyone. @Greenshok..where i can mention the Cascade deletes for Lookup fields.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to do this with a master-detail relationship.  The detail records have the same visibility as the master.  If the detail documents need their own separate permission settings, you'll need to switch to a lookup relationship.